# JADE Hangs when executed on 64Bit Linux at Agent Invocation

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, agents-jade

I've got a pesky issue I hope i can request some assistance from the community on....

I have a Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64 Bit linux *server* on which I run an instance of **JADE** (no gui) that creates a container and connects to a Main RMA on my local machine just fine. I see the container pop up and life is good. The problem is when I re-invoke that same instance using an **Agent** - it *hangs*. Note: I've recompiled the PingAgent Example on the 64Bit machine with the same vintage of Java (8) as on my workstation (windows). Is it a 32 vs 64 bit thing or are there issues with Jade on Linux?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated ....

Below are the particulars:

***Good instance*** (no agent, no hanging ):

**RUN**:

```
versaggi@drools:/usr/local/jade$ java -classpath lib/jade.jar:classes jade.Boot -container -local-host 50.116.61.17 -host versaggi.game-host.org -port 1099
```

**Result**:

```
Aug 12, 2014 7:35:42 PM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer 
INFO: ---------------------------------- 
    This is JADE 4.3.2 - revision 6708 of 2014/03/28 15:19:44 
    downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions, 
    at http://jade.tilab.com/
---------------------------------------- 
Aug 12, 2014 7:35:42 PM jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager initialize 
INFO: Listening for intra-platform commands on address: 
- jicp://50.116.61.17:1099 

Aug 12, 2014 7:35:43 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.management.AgentManagement initialized 
Aug 12, 2014 7:35:43 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.messaging.Messaging initialized 
Aug 12, 2014 7:35:43 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.resource.ResourceManagement initialized 
Aug 12, 2014 7:35:43 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.mobility.AgentMobility initialized 
Aug 12, 2014 7:35:43 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.event.Notification initialized 
Aug 12, 2014 7:35:43 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform 
INFO: -------------------------------------- 
Agent container Container-7@50.116.61.17 is ready. 
--------------------------------------------
```

***Bad Instance*** (Agent Included in invocation, hangs ....)

```
versaggi@drools:/usr/local/jade$ java -classpath lib/jade.jar:classes jade.Boot -container -local-host 50.116.61.17 -host versaggi.game-host.org -port 1099  -**agents** ping1:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent


Aug 12, 2014 7:34:25 PM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer 
INFO: ---------------------------------- 
    This is JADE 4.3.2 - revision 6708 of 2014/03/28 15:19:44 
    downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions, 
    at http://jade.tilab.com/
---------------------------------------- 
Aug 12, 2014 7:34:25 PM jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager initialize 
INFO: Listening for intra-platform commands on address: 
- jicp://50.116.61.17:1099 

Aug 12, 2014 7:34:26 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.management.AgentManagement initialized 
Aug 12, 2014 7:34:26 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.messaging.Messaging initialized 
Aug 12, 2014 7:34:26 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.resource.ResourceManagement initialized 
Aug 12, 2014 7:34:26 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.mobility.AgentMobility initialized 
Aug 12, 2014 7:34:26 PM jade.core.BaseService init 
INFO: Service jade.core.event.Notification initialized 

**< *** HANGS HERE ***>** 

**< *** KILLED FROM RAM HERE ***>**

Aug 12, 2014 7:34:36 PM jade.imtp.leap.NodeSkel executeCommand 
WARNING: Error serving H-Command jade.core.management.AgentManagement/8: java.lang.NullPointerException 
Aug 12, 2014 7:34:36 PM jade.core.messaging.MessageManager shutdown 
INFO: MessageManager shutting down ... 
Aug 12, 2014 7:34:36 PM jade.core.Runtime$1 run 
INFO: JADE is closing down now.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have determined the source of the problem but **not** a solution, most likely because a solutions the this problem may not exist.

The JADE container will eventually complete in time (after a timeout period) but the Agent will NOT be instantiated (See bold error msg below).

The problem is that I am instantiating the Main container on a local PC behind a firewall on a private address 10.0.0.12 port 1099. The remote container is instantiated on a public Linux Server that actually correctly connects to my local PC via a port forward of 1099 rule in my local router to the IP of 10.0.0.12.

The real problem arises because the Main Container which controls the remote containers and thusly the agents dictates that the agent communication must go through 10.0.0.12 port 1099 and conveys that to the remote container on the public linux server, which promptly tries to instantiate the agent communication through 10.0.0.12 port 1099....and consequently times out.

In the invoking JAVA call the option "-host 24.228.171.118 -port 1099" actually points to my router which does a port forward - it is NOT the IP of the PC initiating the Main container.

It appears that this particular set up does not work well inherently ....

You see the issue here ....

If there is a configuration option I can employ to change this (that anyone know of) I'd be grateful....

.

```
versaggi@drools:/usr/local/jade$ java -classpath lib/jade.jar:classes jade.Boot -container -local-host 50.116.61.17 -host 24.228.171.118 -port 1099  -agents ping1:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent
```

.

```
Aug 13, 2014 1:08:20 PM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
INFO: ----------------------------------
    This is JADE 4.3.2 - revision 6708 of 2014/03/28 15:19:44
    downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,
    at http://jade.tilab.com/
----------------------------------------
Aug 13, 2014 1:08:21 PM jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager initialize
INFO: Listening for intra-platform commands on address:
- jicp://50.116.61.17:1099

Aug 13, 2014 1:08:21 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.management.AgentManagement initialized
Aug 13, 2014 1:08:21 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.messaging.Messaging initialized
Aug 13, 2014 1:08:21 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.resource.ResourceManagement initialized
Aug 13, 2014 1:08:21 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.mobility.AgentMobility initialized
Aug 13, 2014 1:08:21 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.event.Notification initialized
```

.

- Aug 13, 2014 1:12:36 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl
  startBootstrapAgents

  SEVERE: *Cannot create agent ping1: Remote object unreachable - Caused
  by:  ICPException delivering command to address*
  **jicp://10.0.0.12:1099**. - Caused by:  Error creating connection.  -
  Caused by:  Connection timed out

.

```
Aug 13, 2014 1:12:36 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
INFO: --------------------------------------
Agent container Container-3@50.116.61.17 is ready.
--------------------------------------------
```

.